# Using sqldb rawQuery with question marks (?) params

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to use ?s as params building my query but there is clearly something wrong with it. Wish the documentation was providing at least one example...

```
SQLDb.rawQuery("SELECT C.?, B.?, B.?, B.? FROM ? C, ? B  WHERE C.? = B.?", new String[] 
               {Tables.CATEGORIES_NAME, Tables.BUDGET_DATE, Tables.BUDGET_VALUE, Tables.KIND, Tables.CATEGORIES, Tables.BUDGET, Tables.CATEGORIES, Tables.TABLE_ID, Tables.TABLE_ID});
```

Those const are all strings, simply names of the columns. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think you can actually use the question mark as place holders for the database tables. I don't know either why would you need that.

Comment: ? should be replaced with string so why would that matter. And i'm trying this to shorten my query... since there is such param as selectionArgs

Comment: Using `?` doesn't append the `String` directly in the query `String` as it's used to prevent malicious stuff(like a `DROP TABLE *` added directly to the query `String` instead of one of the parameters). I'm no database expert so maybe someone with a little  more knowledge would offer an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491107/error-with-simple-parameterized-query-java-sql

Comment: oh it seems not posible then, too bad...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `?` cannot be used for arbitrary pieces of the SQL query. It can be used for values in `WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, and so forth, but it cannot be used for database names, table names, column names, and so on to the left of the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `?` in your query, use `String.format` with `%s` to fill-in table and column names in your query.